# Solving a non linear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, dirac-delta, nonlinear-analysis

This is a first order differential equation:
$$
\frac{df_1}{dx} + \frac{(f_1)^2}{h^2} - \frac{2m}{h^2} \lambda \delta(x-pa)=-\frac{2mE_1}{h^2}
$$

Where, h, $\lambda $ and $E_1$ are constants and and pa lies in [0,a] as 0<p<1 .

I have not been taught how to handle differential equations with a Dirac Delta function in it. Moreover, this is a non linear one. I came across this in a research paper and the answer is given but the method to solve it isn't. I have tried learning to use Laplace transform to solve this, but got stuck again because I didn't know how to do Laplace transform of the second term of the equation.
Any help will be appreciated. Please, help me out.

The answer is:
$f_1=√2mE_1[cot (\frac{√2mE_1}{h} (x-b))]$

Where b is constant of integration

P.s.: I know this might be rude but please don't vote this as a homework question because it isn't one. If you can't help just ignore.

Comment: Would be better to show us the solution. Also plug the known solution into the equation, that should hint you how it can be solved.

Comment: Would be better to hide the ugly constants and translate/rescale the variable. You can rewrite as $g'+g^2=a\delta(x)\pm1.$ ($g:=f/h$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the notation in my comment, for $x\ne0$ the equation

$$g'+g^2=\pm1$$ is separable and the solution will be $g$ as the tangent or hyperbolic tangent of $x$, with constants.

The constants can differ on the left and on the right, and by introducing a discontinuity of height $a$, you will retrieve the Dirac Delta.

---

The solution can be like

$$x<0\to g(x)=-\tan(x+r),\\x>0\to g(x)= -\tan(x+s)$$

and there is a unit step at $x=0$ if $\tan(r)-\tan(s)=1.$

Comment: The answer has a cotangent. Let me edit the question and add in.

Comment: Done! @Yves Daoust

Comment: then you how do we get a cot in the answer?

Comment: @Korra: hem, relation between $\cot$ and $\tan$ ?

Comment: cot is reciprocal of tan.

Comment: @Korra: what else ?

Comment: also, what are r and s in the answer

Comment: @Korra: anything, the equation is autonomous.

Comment: tan(π/2-x)=cot(x)

Comment: @Korra: you have it now !

Comment: Alright! Thank you. I will try it out and see.